# Populate Google Map from database of locations

Tags: wordpress, jquery, google-maps, dictionary

I'm running Nine To Five theme in Wordpress, which is an employment/job system for Wordpress.  It includes a feature to display an individual job's location on a Google Map within the post for that job.

I'd like to display all jobs' location on the same map, with clickable pins taking you to the job details.

The location is stored as a city name in a custom field in post_meta.

**Update**: I think this plugin might be what I need: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/romeluv-google-maps-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [plugin above](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/romeluv-google-maps-for-wordpress/) does what I need, although there are a few bugs in it to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to save latitude and longitude in the database, whenever you are displaying the map get all the latitudes and longitudes and create a marker and put on the map.

Comment: The long and lat don't need to be saved in the database for the google map to work; the city name works.  How do I get the locations of all jobs and place all of them on a single map?